# Finding a module for the series $2^{i}$ from 0 to 219

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, modules

How can I compute this:

$\{ \sum 2^{i}$ for $i \in [0, 219] \} \pmod{13}$

I tried to manipulate the series by using the root principle to find the number of elements divisible by every prime $\leq 13$. However, I failed.

Is there any way to compute this without doing an excessive amount of calculations? I assume there is a way to factorize it so you can find the modules of each factor and make it simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, note that $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{219}2^i=2^{220}-1$.

Now, let's calculate $2^{220}\bmod13$.

Since $\gcd(13,2)=1$, the "cycle" of $2^n\bmod{13}$ consists of $12$ elements:

- $1$
- $2$
- $4$
- $8$
- $3$
- $6$
- $12$
- $11$
- $9$
- $5$
- $10$
- $7$

Therefore, $2^{220}\bmod{13}=2^{220\bmod{12}}\bmod{13}=2^{4}\bmod{13}=3$.

Therefore, $2^{220}-1\bmod{13}=2$.

Comment: Well, it is really easy to prove with that formula, but I am completely lost on how you would get it. Can you explain the process to me?

Comment: @JOX: Which part?

Comment: "Note that"... I'm pretty sure there is a pattern to follow there

Comment: @JOX: $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}2^i=2^{n+1}-1$. You can prove this to yourself by induction, or post it as a separate question here and somebody will do it for you (or will probably give you a link to an identical question) in about 2 seconds.

Comment: It's just the standard formula for the partial sums of the geometric series, that comes from the remarkable identity $$a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\dots+b^{n-1})$$ (Set $a=1,\ b=2$).

Comment: By adding 1 and -1 I could form a pattern where a digit is equal to the sum of everything before it. Thanks.